# For Which Values $cos(\overline{z})$ Is Differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find the values for which $\cos(\overline{z})$ is differentiable

Can we say that $[\cos(\overline{z})]'=\sin(\overline{z})\cdot \overline{z}'$

We know that $\overline{z}$ is not differentiable at any point, but if $z=Re(z)$ it will be.

Is the claim flawed?

Comment: You are asking about complex differentiability?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, the complex values for which it is differentiable

Comment: Perhaps your effort is circular.  The chain rule will be applicable only if $\overline{z}'$ exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\cos (\overline{z})=\cos x \cosh y+i \sin x \sinh y$.

Now check for which values of $z$ the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations are valid.

Answer (score 3):

Use the miraculous [Wirtinger calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives#Functions_of_one_complex_variable_2): the real-differentiable function $f(z)=\cos \overline z$ is complex-differentiable exactly at the points $z$ where $\frac {\partial f}{\partial  \overline z}(z)=-\sin \overline z$ is zero, namely at the points $$z\in \pi\mathbb Z$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate? we take the derivative with respect to  $\overline{z}$?

Comment: In order to learn the (easy) formalism of the Wirtinger calculus you could read the Wikipedia article I linked to or Chapter 1, §4 of [this book by Remmert](https://books.google.fr/books?id=uP8SF4jf7GEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false).